# Craft ships with PHPUnit... How can we use it to test our plugins?

Tags: plugin-development

Since Craft ships with a copy of PHPUnit, is it possible to use that to run tests on a plugin? Or do we need to have a separate copy installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, see this example plugin by Selvin Ortiz: https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.loath.

You can also check out https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import for some detailed unit tests.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Bob, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: That plugin uses: `/craft/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.php`, 
`/craft/app/tests/bootstrap.php`, 
and `/craft/app/tests/phpunit.xml` which doesn't ship in the latest version of Craft 2 anyone.

Comment: True. I still provide these files myself for now and I'm not sure what Craft's future philosophy on testing will be.